# ​[Prelude] to a tag disambiguation

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

I've noticed that the tag [prelude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prelude) is being used in to refer to both:

1. An enhanced Emacs configuration that should make your experience with Emacs both more pleasant and more powerful. [link](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude)
2. The standard Haskell module that is imported by default into all Haskell modules. [link](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html)

Any suggestions for how to handle this tag?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suggest splitting the single [prelude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prelude) tag, into 2 more focused tags.

1. For emacs, there should be a tag [emacs-prelude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs-prelude).
2. For Haskell, there should be a tag [haskell-prelude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-prelude).

This will solve the issue of ambiguity.

It turns out that [emacs-prelude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs-prelude) already exists, with 6 questions tagged.

If this is done, I also believe that the regular [prelude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prelude) tag should probably be blacklisted to prevent future confusion amongst these narrowed tags.

Comment: This sounds good to me. Do you know how to go about making it happen?

Comment: @martin first edit the description of the _prelude_ tag to ask to stop using it, then retag.

Comment: @Cœur mind giving me a hand creating the [tag:haskell-prelude] tag? I'm short on rep on this stack.

Comment: @Cœur That should do it. Thanks!